# If integrating with respective to full circle which limit we should use?

Tags: integration

> If integrating with respective to full circle which limit we should use?

Option 1) $-π$ to $+π$

Option 2) $0$ to $2π$

Im just confused about angles as limit type of integration.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use the [mathjax basic tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and review the [meta read](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and enhance your question. It helps to include context (i.e., your attempts, motivation, etc).

Comment: Both should work equally well.

Comment: Normally one would choose $[0,2\pi]$. If you choose $[-\pi,\pi]$ this is still equivalent to option $2$.

Comment: For any $a$, $a$ to $a+2\pi$ will do.